# Was I wrong? Should I have added clarity to my answer using a reference of another's answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

[Possible bug in jQuery 1.6 - $(...).attr("checked") is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969598/possible-bug-in-jquery-1-6-attrchecked-is-not-working/5969631#5969631)

Neal & I answered nearly at the same time.  My initial answer didn't reference the link to the new 1.6.1 RC for jQuery.  However, I felt that @Neal's answer didn't fully clarify that in that link it mentioned that 1.5.2 users (what @Andrey was using) could go straight to 1.6.1 RC and avoid 1.6 and not have to change their code.

I believe I was adding a second option in my answer to @Andrey's question and did it since I didn't think @Neal's answer was clear enough.

@Neal called me on it as his position is that I should have added a comment instead of adding to my answer using his reference. :-)  You can see the comment exchange for his & my position.

I must admit I have been thinking about this for the past few days.  Who's right?

Should I have added a comment clarifying going straight to 1.6.1 RC on @Neal's answer or was I within the valid range of answer etiquette?

I have read:

[Referencing other answers - acceptable or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/referencing-other-answers-acceptable-or-not)

[An elegant solution for "answer-stealing" edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/an-elegant-solution-for-answer-stealing-edits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on this; bear in mind that I know nothing about jQuery. Neal's answer cites prior discussion, suggests a code change, and mentions that 1.6.1 might be worth looking at but not precisely why. Your answer (in its current state) explains why the asker's code isn't working, and suggests upgrading directly to 1.6.1 (and explains why), but gives no solution if the asker sticks to 1.6.0. So the two answers have about half the technical content in common and different recommendations. Each has enough substance to stand on its own.

Comment: Then it is your opinion that referencing @Neal's post with adding the reason to use 1.6.1 was in fact an acceptable use of referencing another answer in my answer..?

Comment: @klabranche: Yes, I don't see how citing your source could be unacceptable.