# Editing Incorrect Answers to Match Correct Answer(s) After an Extended Period of Time

Tags: support, specific-question, etiquette

I'm pretty new to SO (48 days into it) and I enjoy reading/contributing quite a bit. I ran into one issue today that I found frustrating...

I posted an answer to a simple question today. At (almost) exactly the same time, another, incorrect answer was posted. Much to my surprise, the incorrect answer began receiving up-votes! I quickly (and respectfully) pointed out to the poster that their answer was incorrect. **Forty minutes later**, they edited their response, copied my answer and began receiving more up-votes.

**Question:**

Is this a generally accepted practice? If not, Is this a "flag worthy" issue?

**Disclaimer:**

I understand that this is not a *huge* issue. I'm just attempting to learn proper SO etiquette. Personally, I would have deleted the incorrect post after that period of time, instead of editing it.

**EDIT**

Link, as requested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599818/google-maps-hello-world-problem/6599886#6599886

Comment: This has been discussed before, although I don't have a good link handy. The general consensus seems to be "We empathize; it totally sucks that someone stole 'your' rep. Ultimately, the important thing is that the right info is out there. Be the better person and just find a new question to answer."

Comment: Related: [to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643)

Comment: possible duplicate of [An elegant solution for "answer-stealing" edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/an-elegant-solution-for-answer-stealing-edits)

Comment: So what happened? The linked-to question got removed completely. So maybe we should now close this Q as duplicate (see link reference provided by M.Tibbits in an earlier comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens, unfortunately.  I don't think it's "flag-worthy", but it's very certainly rude on the part of the person who does that to you.  It's happened to me before, and they certainly get a downvote from me for etiquette breach, even when the answer is right.  My best advice is to walk away and let it be; otherwise, there almost certainly will be a flamewar in comments, which is never pretty.

Comment: +1 Post in question *has* a bit of flamewar in comments...